# Join time series in matlab and replace missing data points with NaN

Tags: matlab, nan

I am trying to join 2 different time series in matlab and create a common time vector and would appreciate some help. I dont want to interpolate any values but rather replace missing data points with NaNs and fill these in later with something like the repnan function, so I cannot use the interp1 or the synchronize function in matlab from what I understand since these always interpolate.
Assume I have the matrices

```
 a =
 1    40
 2    50
 3    60
 5    70
 6    80
```

and

```
 b =
 2    60
 3    70
 4    80
 5    90
 7   100
```

then i use

```
 time = union(a(:,1), b(:,1))
```

to get the common time vector i want

```
 time =
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
```

Now I want a new matrix where I can have the values from a and b where available and NaN when there are no values for a given time. For example if I use

```
 fill_a = ismember(time, a(:,1))
 fill_a =
 1
 1
 1
 0
 1
 1
 0
```

I want the observations from a to be where the ones are, and NaN where the zeroes are and put this into a new matrix with the common time stamps.
I want it to look like

```
 finished =
 1    40   NaN
 2    50    60
 3    60    70
 4   NaN    80
 5    70    90
 6    80   NaN
 7   NaN   100
```

Any help is appreciated. Also I would prefer not to loop if possible if it is slow. Thanks in advance.

Comment: other related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10877772/97160, http://stackoverflow.com/q/7919144/97160

Comment: after you created `fill_a` and `fill_b`, just add:

`time(find(fill_a),2) = a(:,2);
time(find(~fill_a),2) = nan;
time(find(fill_b),3) = b(:,2);
time(find(~fill_b),3) = nan;`

Comment: Or if possible, declare time as an nxm matrix of nan values if you know the size. That way you can do what I wrote before, but skip two commands. The `time(find(~fill_x),2) = nan;`can be ignored. That will save some computation power.